# Using available Lucene Indexes in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I am trying to use solr to search using indexes created by lucene.I tried [Can a raw Lucene index be loaded by Solr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715973/can-a-raw-lucene-index-be-loaded-by-solr)
the answer given in this post.Changed solrschema and config as explained also added all the fields. I did not get any error in Tomcat and am able to see Solr admin page.

However when I query I am not getting any results.there is no error but solr is not returning any results on the query( numcount=0)

Could any one please help with this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [LukeRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler) to see what's going on.

Comment: Hey...so there was a version mismatch earlier.I got the correct version bet can not see anything in luke request handler.Numer of docs is 0.Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a Lucene version mismatch. You can find this out by checking the logs. But first, click on STATISTICS. Does SOLR see that that there are records in the index? Then go back to the admin page and click on ANALYSIS to see all of your fields, their definition, and some stats about the indexed records.

If all this checks out, try a query of "*:*" which will return 10 records from your index.

If that works then you probably have a logic error in your query.

Comment: There was lucene version mismatch. I got that correct now.but cant see anything in stat,analysis.What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working. So I copied my index in the data folder but not in the folder named index. When I found this out I copied all the index files to the index folder however files names segments.* were newly created by solr.I did not replace these files with the old files.
After doing that it started working fine. :)