# Is there a generic web frontend for Lucene?

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm building an application that has to store some gigabytes of log data (not exactly log data but similar) in a way so that the log data can be queried efficiently. I'm planning to use Lucene or something based on Lucene. While the data enters the index via the API I'd prefer not to build my own frontend for querying the data. I don't need anything fancy here, just a simple way to query the index.

I'm not sure if Solr would solve my problem. Is there something like a generic web frontend for querying Lucene indexes?

Comment: As a comment, as I do not have experience with it:[Banana](https://github.com/LucidWorks/banana). This is a port of Kibana.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solr has the [Velocity UI Response Writer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Velocity+Search+UI) which is a general search interface for Lucene indexes. Should probably work fine as long as you're able to serve your indexes through Solr. See [Can a raw Lucene index be loaded by Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715973/can-a-raw-lucene-index-be-loaded-by-solr) for how to do this.

Comment: Thanks, looks good! I'll just keep the question open for a few hours in case somebody else has another idea.