# Solr: import Lucene index while server is up and running

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, solrj

As read here [Can a raw Lucene index be loaded by Solr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715973/can-a-raw-lucene-index-be-loaded-by-solr) Lucene indexes can be imported into Solr. This works well when the Solr server is not running (creating a Solr core folder structure in the data folder with all the needed configuration files) but it does not work when the Solr server is up and running.

Is there any call (via rest endpoint or java api) to tell Solr to re-scan the data folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to generate an index with lucene (outsite solr) and insert this to solr without restart.

You must not change the index-folder directly. But you can [create](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API#CoreAdminAPI-CREATE) a new core which point to the already build index folder and [switch/swap](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API#CoreAdminAPI-SWAP) the core with the (outdated) old one. Or you can [merge](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API#CoreAdminAPI-MERGEINDEXES) the new index-Folder in the old core.

All this can be done by the [solrj admin api](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_4_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/request/CoreAdminRequest.Create.html).

e.g. create:

```java
    CoreAdminRequest.Create req = new CoreAdminRequest.Create();
    req.setConfigName(configName);
    req.setSchemaName(schemaName);
    req.setDataDir(dataDir);
    req.setCoreName(coreName);
    req.setInstanceDir(instanceDir);
    req.setIsTransient(true);
    req.setIsLoadOnStartup(false); // <= unless its productive core.
    return req.process(adminServer);
```

e.g. the swap:

```java
    CoreAdminRequest request = new CoreAdminRequest();
    request.setAction(CoreAdminAction.SWAP);
    request.setCoreName(coreName1);
    request.setOtherCoreName(coreName2);
    request.process(solrClient);
```

For SolrCloud use the first "create" approach with the [collections api](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API) and use alias instead of swap.

e.g. the alias:

```java
    CollectionAdminRequest.CreateAlias req = new CollectionAdminRequest.CreateAlias();
    req.setAliasedCollections(coreName);
    req.setAliasName(aliasName);
    return req.process(solrClient);
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I would like to use the swap solution through the solrj admin api but I don't see any method for that.