# Import existing Lucene indexes to Solr

Tags: java, search, lucene, solr

What is the best method for importing existing Lucene indexes to Solr?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715973/can-a-raw-lucene-index-be-loaded-by-solr

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195404/very-basic-dude-with-solr-lucene