# Sphinx Search, compound key

Tags: mysql, search-engine, sphinx

After my previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217522/best-way-to-search-for-partial-words-in-large-mysql-dataset), I've chosen Sphinx as the search engine above my MySQL database.

I've done some small tests with it, and it looks great. However, i'm at a point right now, where I need some help / opinions.

I have a table articles (structure isn't important), a table properties (structure isn't important either), and a table with values of each property per article (this is what it's all about).
The table where these values are stored, has the following structure:

```
articleID   UNSIGNED INT
propertyID  UNSIGNED INT
value       VARCHAR(255)
```

The primary key is a compound key of articleID and propertyID.

I want Sphinx to search through the `value` column. However, to create an index in Sphinx, I need a unique id. I don't have right here.
Also when searching, I want to be able to filter on the propertyID column (only search values for propertyID 2 for example, which I can do by defining it as attribute).

On the Sphinx forum, I found I could create a multi-value attribute, and set this as query for my Sphinx index:

```
SELECT articleID, value, GROUP_CONCAT(propertyID) FROM t1 GROUP BY articleID
```

articleID will be unique now, however, now I'm missing values. So I'm pretty sure this isn't the solution, right?

There are a few other options, like:

- Add an extra column to the table, which is unique
- Create a calculated unique value in the query (like `articleID*100000+propertyID`)

Are there any other options I could use, and what would you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your suggestions

- Add an extra column to the table, which is unique

*This can not be done for an existing table with large number of records as adding a new field to a large table take some time and during that time the database will not be responsive.*

- Create a calculated unique value in the query (like articleID*100000+propertyID)

*If you do this you have to find a way to get the articleID and propertyID from the calculated unique id.*

**Another alternative way is that you can create a new table having a key field for sphinx and another two fields to hold articleID and propertyID.**

- **new_sphinx_table** with following fields

  id - UNSIGNED INT/ BIGINT

  articleID - UNSIGNED INT

  propertyID - UNSIGNED INT

Then you can write an indexing query like below

```
SELECT id, t1.articleID, t1.propertyID, value FROM t1 INNER JOIN new_sphinx_table nt ON t1.articleID  = nt.articleID AND t1.propertyID = nt.propertyID;
```

This is a sample so you can modify it to fit to your requirements.

What sphinx return is matched new_sphinx_table.id values with other attributed columns. You can get result by using **new_sphinx_table.id** values and joining your **t1** named table and **new_sphinx_table**

Comment: Thans for you answer. If i create a calcuated unqiue value, it is possbile to get the both ID's back. But it's not a really nice way of course...

Comment: If you do that, you need a field 2*(INT) size field to store combined key value in database, or else whenever you re-index the database, you have to recalculate it. Think you planned to re-index your DB once a day and the DB table contains 100000 records so the computation cost will be higher. And future growth of the users would make it more difficult.

Comment: Yes. It isn't a good option. I will wait a few days more to see if other people have other opinions about my question, before marking it as an answer.

Comment: You are correct. There will be a better solution as there is no best solution. Making a post as an answer in short time, it will discourage others posting different idea.