# django haystack: which search engine would be better

Tags: django, search-engine, django-haystack

I'm building a Django project that needs a good search functionality

Which of the search engines out of these would be good to use with [django haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/)

- solr
- elasticsearch
- Xapian

One other advice I need is should I prefer going with above or use [django-elasticsearch](https://github.com/aparo/django-elasticsearch)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Personally, I've used both Solr and ElasticSearch with with django haystack and have been happy with the results from both. Solr seemed to have a slightly steeper learning curve, but it wasn't enough to be a deal breaker. If you have a cloud-based implementation in mind for your project, you may want to go with ElasticSearch as it features distributed indexing and some other useful features that kind of environment. I don't have any experience with Xapian, so I won't mislead you with any information there.

You may want to check out this post from the creator of ElasticSearch https://stackoverflow.com/a/2288211/1608085 (yes, it will be a bit biased)

Also check out this previous answer for a comparison of Solr and ElasticSearch
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10213568/1608085

Answer (score 1):

I`ve been working in a [project](http://ensaiosclinicos.gov.br) that uses solr to perform searches. It is a good solution.

A more extended input to this you can find here - [Why use Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/WhyUseSolr)

Comment: Please avoid linking to external content - if you can, summarize it in your own words, this helps us avoid having useless dangling links should linked content disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you consider such powerfull search engine like Sphinx - [django-sphinx](https://github.com/dcramer/django-sphinx)

Comment: Instead of asking "Why", it would be more useful to list a few reasons if you are familiar with Sphinx and can compare it with ElasticSearch & Solr.

Comment: Answer to why **because its no longer maintained**