# MongoDB Full Text Search of Rich Documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, full-text-search, elasticsearch

I'm developing an Node.js app that stores HTML documents in a MongoDB database and want to provide full text search capabilities. From what I can see the full text search included in MongoDB expects documents to be plain text and therefore isn't suitable for indexing my html documents. Is that assumption correct and if so what do folks recommend for this.

From reading other [SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015887/mongodb-full-text-search-options) Elastic Search seems to be the most suggested path. I can't say I'm all that happy about bringing a Java app into the picture though. Also having a completely separate app is not my ideal scenario.

Comment: Well you have a choice, use a separate app or don't. SO doesn't really do polling to find out if you should or not, that choice is yours alone.

Comment: Ok let me rephrase. Is there a way to filter the text that MongoDB uses for it's full text search, such that I could strip content such as HTML markup so it wasn't included in the index?

Answer (score 1):

You can throw some regex at the HTML and try to [strip the markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript) from the HTML yourself. The output can be indexed by MongoDB.

That is probably easier to develop than using a search tool such as ES or Solr (which indeed is out of scope here), but it won't get you as far: simply stripping the HTML means that contextual information is lost, and invalid HTML can lead to trouble.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean I need to store each document twice, once with the HTML which wouldn't be included in the Mongo FTS, and a second time as plain text which would be included in the Mongo FTS?

Comment: Yes, but since the HTML doesn't need to be indexed, that should not be a big problem. Also, the size of text is comparatively small, even if you crawl pages like crazy. If you're worried about the space requirements, the text index will be the bigger problem. The HTML can also be compressed because it can't be searched (in any reasonably fast manner) anyway.

Comment: Indexing data always means storing it twice: once for keeping plain document and once with index for quick searching (usually it is difficult or not possible to recreate fully readable document from full-text index). It also applies for ES. It will "waste" additional storage for the index, and (what can be disabled) for the the source document. Method suggested by @mnemosyn is actually what ES is doing with its "analyzers" transforming the input into searchable dictionary of tokens. ES is just carefully implemented to conform standard with multiple document formats.

Comment: Thanks and yes I understand the need to duplicate the text for for FTS. However using MongoDB in this manner means the text is stored 3 times, the 3rd being for the Mongo index. This seems sub-optimal in both time and space. Further the html documents are fully editable so all 3 copies would need to be continually updated. A more efficient solution would be for MongoDB to enable a function to be called that could filter out content you didn't want included in the full text index.