# MongoDB full text search in production?

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

Does anyone have experience of using MongoDB full text search in production? 
What advice can you give me about that? 
I think it is a little risky to use it in production because it's in beta state. Am i right?

Comment: You would have to be crazy to use it in production

Comment: @Sammaye ...because...

Comment: @Philipp Considering the details that could change (like there has been talk about changing the language field to ISO) in the implementation to use it in production is just asking for trouble, it is like throwing away everything you know about stable programming and just going for whatever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Currently (September 2013) The MongoDB fulltext search is still in beta stage. [The documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-text-search/) explicitely warns from using it:</strike>

> The text search is currently a beta feature
>
> [...]
>
> Warning:
>
> •Do not enable or use text search on production systems.

Likely reasons for this warning:

1. Implementation- and API details are subject to change. Anything you develop and which works now could fail the next time you update MongoDB.
2. It isn't fully tested. There could still be obscure bugs lurking in it which could break your application.

For these reasons you should not use it in a real-world application before 10gen has declared it finished.

Update: As of Version 2.6, text search has production quality.

Comment: but I did it anyway and it seems ok.  Probably better to use elastisearch though, I was just lazy