# Indexing and searching in hadoop

Tags: search, solr, indexing

Could somebody tell me how can address the below mentioned issue?

I have a large number of text files which are stored in HDFS. My client application need to find related files of a particular search word. I would like to know whether it is possible with Apache Solr. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the first question that you need to think about is if the search will be realtime (index will be updated very often) or will it be less often. If, it is the former, then I would strongly advise you to use Elastic Search. And, dont rely solely on my advice. This question has some very good answers to Elastic Search vs Solr Debate.

[Solr vs. ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213009/solr-vs-elasticsearch)

And, as for your question regarding the use of hadoop in Apache Solr, here are some useful links that I found off the internet

http://www.likethecolor.com/2010/09/26/using-hadoop-to-create-solr-indexes

http://architects.dzone.com/articles/solr-hadoop-big-data-love