# Where do I find useful info on using Lucene and Compass?

Tags: java, lucene, compass-lucene

I am learning Lucene and Compass (Compass is because the code I am working on is old) and I am trying to find something on where to start (and even what to start reading). The Lucene in Action is to old, the code doesn't even run so that is not useful. Nor do I know if I should be reading a lot about Lucene if I am going to use Compass?

And where do I find good texts about Compass? The documentation was pretty technical and expected knowledge in Lucene.

Answer (score 1):

`Development on Compass was stopped around 2010`, since you are learning, you should invest in learning [Elastic Search](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) rather than Compass. Elastic Search was created by the same guy who created Compass, since Compass is not a scalable solution the development was stopped & he created Elastic Search.

Elastic Search relies on Lucene at its core. [Elastic Search Guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/)

[Lucene In Action - 2nd Edition 2010](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988177) is the best & authoritative information you will find on Lucene. Unless you want to have the very latest of whats happening with Lucene, this book is your best bet it covers more than 99% of what you may need to get started.

Also you could consider [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). With latest 4.0 release Lucene & Solr became a singe project with focus on Cloud & distributed searching.

Check this [Solr vs ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213009/solr-vs-elasticsearch).

Comment: The problem is that I am working on legacy code so Elastic Search is not an option at the moment. Do you know about other Compass resourceS?

Comment: Sorry I thought you were learning, Your best bet is to check [Compass Forum](http://forum.compass-project.org/forum.jspa?forumID=37). FYI, Compass latest releases uses Lucene 2.4. Check [dependencies](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.compass-project/compass/2.2.0-RC2). Sorry I couldn't be of more help, I haven't used Compass much.