# Search Box in Symfony2 with Solr

Tags: php, search, symfony, solr

I want to create *Search box* in front page of my website but I don't know how to create one  using *Solr*. All my website is developed in **Symfony2**. I don't use Database for searching.

How I can do this?.

In my project *Solr* bundle use this:

```
use SolrClient;
use SolrQuery;
use SolrObject;
use SolrDocument;
use SolrInputDocument;
```

In base *twig* file :

```
<form action="{{ path("home_search") }}" method="get">
  <input type="search" name="search"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="search">
</form>
```

Some example of my controller:

```
public function searchAction($templateName = '')
{
 $solrService = $this->get('rocket.solr_service');

    $solrQuery = new SolrQuery('*:*');
    $solrQuery->addField('id')
        ->addField('name');


    if (!empty($templateName)) {
        $solrQuery->addFilterQuery(sprintf('name:"%s" OR design_template_tag_name:"%1$s" OR design_category_name:"%1$s"',
                                           $templateName));
    }


    $solrQuery->setRows(1000);

    $solrObject = $solrService->query(
        'RocketBraPrintBundle:DesignTemplate',
        $solrQuery,
        SolrService::WRITER_FORMAT_SOLR_OBJECT
    );

    $templates = $solrObject->offsetGet('response')->offsetGet('docs');
    if (!$templates) {

        if (!empty($templateName)) {
            $this->setFlash('catalog-message', 'No results found for your search.');
            return $this->searchDesignTemplates($categoryTreeSlug,
                                                $productFamilyFaceId);
        }

        return array();
    }

    return $templates;

}
```

But in twig file where this is render I don't know what I will write.

Comment: What bundle are you using to connect and search in solr ?

Comment: @ArtemL thanks for comment .I am using solr bundle and for searching nothing because i am new in search with solr.

Comment: What bundle you are using exactly? And how? Some cod may help answering the question.

Comment: @ArtemL I have edited my question you can see that deps file and i have no any code for search.

Comment: Can't see any solr bundle. Can you point out which bundle you are already using with solr?

Comment: @ArtemL see this edited question and in project use this with apacheSolr.

Comment: You are not using any of Symfony2 bundles. Consider looking in one of these: [KNP Bundles SOLR](http://knpbundles.com/search?q=solr). I'm using [NelmioSolariumBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioSolariumBundle), but seems it's incompatible with Symfony2.0.x you are using.

Comment: Thanks. Any other suggestion because my project totally made in symfon2.

Comment: @ArtemL you can see my controller.I know this is wrong but may be this is helpful for you.

Comment: @KunwarSiddharthSingh Have you considered using ElasticSearch? Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213009/solr-vs-elasticsearch for a comparison. If you opt for it, check out here for a tutorial on how to integrate with Symfony: http://richardmiller.co.uk/2011/11/11/symfony2-integrating-elasticsearch/

Comment: As mentioned by @ArtemL, the Solarium Bundle is the best option. I don't see why it wouldn't work with Symfony2.0 though. You would just have to install it like anything else in Symfony2.0, by modifying the deps, autoload, and AppKernel files.

Answer (score 2):

you can use  https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioSolariumBundle  with use solarium implementation

Really great for better solr query

i already use it

here a sample

```
    $query = 'foo';

    $page = 1;
    if (array_key_exists('page', $params)) {
        $page = (int) $params['page'];
    }
    $rows = 10;
    if (array_key_exists('limit', $params)) {
        $rows = (int) $params['limit'];
    }

    $solarium = $this->get('solarium.client');

    //select
    $select = $solarium->createSelect();
    $escapedQuery = $select->getHelper()->escapePhrase($query);

    //dismax
    $dismax = $select->getDisMax();
    // override the default setting of 'dismax' to enable 'edismax'
    $dismax->setQueryParser('edismax');
    //fields
    $dismax->setQueryFields(
                    array('title^5','description^0.7'));

    $select->setQuery($escapedQuery);

    //limit
    $select->setRows($rows);
    $select->setStart(($page - 1) * $rows);

    //type spot only
    $select->createFilterQuery('typeFilter')
            ->setQuery(sprintf('type:%s', 'spot'));

    $resultset = $solarium->select($select);
```

use foreach   or twig  "for in" to display your solr doc

Comment: I have solarium set up and I am able to make queries as shown however I am struggling to try and index my documents. I have a Symfony2 annotated object and I have a method toSolrDocument(\Solarium_Document_ReadWrite $doc) to translate the document as shown in Xavier Briand's presentation. However, when i call it like so foreach ($sheets as $sheet) {
            $documents[] = $sheet->toSolrDocument($update->createDocument());
        } I get  'Solarium_Document_ReadWrite' not found any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: It's weird, Are you sure your solarium lib is in your vendor lib ? Make sure you use solarium 2.4.x, last release 3.x uses php 5.3 namespaces

Comment: I resolved the issue by removing the requirement for the readwrite class. However, I have a new issue having multiple cores. I have set up multiple cores in my solr example installation and added the core i require to my symfony2 config however, somehow the default core I am getting access to is the one specified in the sorl.xml file under the defaultCoreName property. Any ideas?

Comment: please open a new question, it is not related to the searchbox question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this..

Controlloer.php:

```
public function searchAction($templateName = '')
{
    // ------
    // ------

    $resultset = $solrObject->offsetGet('response');

    // Do some error checks

    return array('resultset'=>$resultset);

}
```

twig:

```
<ul>
{% for doc in resultset %}
  <li> {{ doc.name }} </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I still have not tried, but you can try use this new [Jobeet tutorial](http://www.intelligentbee.com/blog/2013/08/29/symfony2-jobeet-day-17-search/) in Symfony2 that explains how to build a system and also how to use Solr in it.
I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You get GET-parameters via

$searchName = $request->query->get('search_name');

But for this you still need the $request variable. You can use it as parameter and change your method signature to this:

public function anagraficaAction(Request $request)

This way, you can call the $request parameter in your method.

The other way is to get the request of the current controller inside your method.

$request = $this->get('request');

Using this you can change your setParameter to this:

setParameter('nome', $searchName)