# Best Lucene search platform in 2013: Solr or ElasticSearch?

Tags: c#, solr, lucene, full-text-search, elasticsearch

I run a job board (PostJobFree.com) with about 1M resumes in it. Average resume size is about 4000 bytes.
PostJobFree uses ASP.NET/C#/SQL Server 2008 R2 and MS SQL Full Text search.

From reading various articles I believe that switching to Apache Lucene search would make searches faster and more scalable. But I never tried it yet.

**Question 1**: Is it the right choice to switch away from MS SQL Full Text Search to Apache Lucene at about 1M documents mark or I would not notice significant search speed increase yet?
I anticipate about 10%/month growth in the number of searchable documents in my database.

**Question 2**: What is the best Lucene platform: Solr or ElasticSearch?

Here’s what I found so far:

**1. Google Search Trends**
http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=elasticsearch%20search%2C%20solr%20search%2C%20sphinx%20search%2C%20%22sql%20server%22%20%22full-text%20search%22&cmpt=q
As of now (April 2013)

- Solr seems to be the most popular search platform at the moment,
  but Solr popularity did not grow at all in the last year (April 2012
  – April 2013).
- ElasticSearch is growing rapidly starting from the
  end of 2010, but still is only about 40% as popular Solr.
- Sphinx search grew in popularity 2006-2009 and is on decline starting from
  the year of 2009. Now it's about as popular as ElasticSearch.
- SQL Server Full-Text search is on the long-term decline.

Do these trends correlate with the quality of these search platforms?

**2. Past StackOverflow questions**

StackOverflow had search platform comparison question in February 2010: [ElasticSearch, Sphinx, Lucene, Solr, Xapian. Which fits for which usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271600/elasticsearch-sphinx-lucene-solr-xapian-which-fits-for-which-usage)

“ElasticSearch” answer by its creator Shay Banon was the favorite back then.

Similar question was asked later in 2012: [Solr vs. ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213009/solr-vs-elasticsearch)

The most popular answer was again in favor of ElasticSearch.

**3. Other**

Nick Zadrosny (who runs both Solr hosting service websolr.com and ElasticSearch hosting service bonsai.io) was a proponent of ElasticSearch in April 2012:
https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3833735

Here's Nick's answer today (April 2013):

> Elasticsearch does tend to be a bit more beginner friendly compared to
>   Solr. Elasticsearch has a nicer API and is definitely easier to set up
>   and configure for a new application. That said, Solr still has some
>   advantage in terms of maturity and robustness, and the learning curve
>   isn't too unreasonable when you don't need to worry about production
>   configuration. Beyond that, both share the same roots in Lucene, and
>   offer similar functionality. Either should be equally appropriate for
>   your needs.

I wonder what exactly does "robustness" mean and how that difference in robustness would change in the coming years?

**4. Percolation**

ElasticSearch has Percolation feature that should allow me to implement resume search alerts with immediate delivery. Does Solr have anything like that?

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty subjective/localized question, and I'll contribute my own vote to close as such, but I will take a stab at an answer anyway since I was quoted in the question.

Solr will always have a lot of legacy interfaces and APIs to support, but it is well known and well proven. Elasticsearch's fresh start has made for a superior developer experience, particularly for beginners, but there is still room for it to grow and mature under the hood.

The decision between the two is highly subjective. My current recommendation is this: if you are in doubt, start with Elasticsearch. The concepts you learn there will translate well to Solr should later circumstances demand a switch.

Beyond that, evaluate the rest of the ecosystem. Such as the availability and quality of tutorials, documentation, and quality open source clients for your particular programming language. Or the availability of hosting providers, consultants and commercial support contracts.

Ultimately I very think that both Solr and Elasticsearch are working toward the same goals, competing for the same user base, and will converge on a similar level of functional parity with each other.

Comment: In 2015, I think Elasticsearch has closed the resiliency gap much more quickly than Solr has closed the usability gap. These days my opinion is thus: if you have a specific reason to use Solr, great, use it; otherwise I recommend Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

As Nick said, I would say give them a try.
After some minutes, it should be very clear.

When I discovered Elasticsearch in 2011, it was pretty clear that this project will become a major one. This is what is happening now. I started to use it in production during summer 2011. Very stable.

*Disclaimer*: I work now at elasticsearch.com but I will have gave you the same answer some months ago!