# Differences between search tools - Solr, Bing and Google?

Tags: search, solr, bing, google-search, google-search-api

I am interested to know how solr search differs from what Bing and Google Search APIs offer?

Answer (score 1):

In Solr you will have your own installation for searching your own documents. Bing and Google are public search engines for public documents.

Comment: That is understandable. Apart from that, what are some of the advantages to develop search on an application using solr vs using Bing Api?

Comment: rather..what is that something that Bing/Google can perform which Solr cannot or viceversa?

Comment: As stated earlier you can't index your own private repository with those API's. Solr also provides a large variety of rankers, and can be embedded on your application. Eventually all depends on what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: could you please explain what you meant by "large variety of rankers"

Comment: From the documentation, "Relevancy is the quality of results returned from a query, encompassing both what documents are found, and their relative ranking (the order that they are returned to the user.)" Have a look at, http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for a few features, a set of plusses and minuses to decide between parity products.  Solr and Google don't differ in features, though, they differ in kind.  They don't solve the same problems.  For many of the Solr implementations I've seen and heard about, Google wouldn't be a bad choice, it would be a nonsensical one.

Looking at Solr and ElasticSearch would invite [such a comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213009/solr-vs-elasticsearch), as would comparing [Google to Bing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bing#Bing_It_On).  The two classes are just too different to provide the point by point analysis though.

The brief description on the [Solr frontpage](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) may help you here, and [their wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/) contains a lot of information to get to understand the software a bit better.

Comment: could you please elaborate - "two classes are just too different to provide the point by point analysis"? please explain how are they different? My understanding is Solr and Bing both offer search engines?

Comment: Reading the Solr frontpage, linked above, should give you some idea of what Solr is.  If, upon learning a bit about it, you have a more specific question to ask, please open a new one.