# Solr or Elastic Search, which one we have to choose if we need customizablity along with scalability

Tags: solr, lucene, elasticsearch

I am in a great confusion that which search engine I have to use for our site, [azzist.com](http://www.azzist.com). It is a job site. We have around 30,000 professionals and 3000 employers. So not only customization of search, but also scalability is important to us. 
[this link](http://www.elasticsearchtutorial.com/elasticsearch-vs-solr.html) helped me a lot. And also I refered [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213009/solr-vs-elasticsearch). But still I can't make a decision. I am still in a confusion that which part I have to compromise. As a job site, which one I have to choose? Now we are using solr. But we need to improve the search results. Please help me.

I know this question will be closed soon, but there is no place for me to ask help.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**: I am an elasticsearch employee.

I would say only: "just give elasticsearch a try and you will probably find the answer yourself after some hours or days."

Comment: I am going through elastic search tutorials now... :)

Answer (score 2):

[www.jobbasket.co.uk](http://www.jobbasket.co.uk)

is built atop of SOLR, we tried Elastic Search at the time but ended up choosing SOLR due to it's ease of interaction with our development language and its maturity.