# Which is better Apache solr or Elastic search?

Tags: performance, solr, elasticsearch, search-engine, database-performance

I started creating my new search application.  In my earlier application I used Apache solr.  Now I want to know which better in terms of performance and usability.

Personally I want to know the performance benchmark of Elastic search and solr. If there are other alternatives suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solr vs. ElasticSearch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213009/solr-vs-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I work at elasticsearch.com

I would just say: give elasticsearch a try. I think that after some hours (minutes?), you will have somehow an opinion.
Start 2 or 3 or 4 nodes, and you will see how things are rebalanced nicely.

About performance, I'd say that elasticsearch will give you a constant query throughput even if you are doing massive index operations.

Comment: Although I am huge fan of ES and we use it at paytm.com, but thats too subjective a statement from somebody working at es.com :)

Comment: That's exactly why I added this disclaimer! Happy that somehow as a fan you can confirm what I said! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have used both quite a bit, and much prefer ElasticSearch.  The API is more flexible and accessible.  It is easier to get started with.  Replication happens automatically by default.  In general all the defaults are easier to work with.  Everything generally works out of the box (safe defaults) and you only need to tune what you find needs to work better.

I have not worked much with SOLR 4, only with 3.x.  Once I switched I never looked back, but I hear that there are many improvements in 4 with regards to replication and clustering that make it a usable competitor.

With regards to performance, I think that generally they are comparable as they both rely on Lucene.   That is why there is a lack of valid benchmarks that make this general comparison.  That said, there are certainly use cases where one will perform better than the other.

If you look at the trends of utilization while there are many more people currently using SOLR, it is in decline.  That decline is very correlated to the increase in users of Elasticsearch which is very much on the rise.  As Dadoonet said, give ElasticSearch a try, it won't take long and you won't want to use SOLR again.

UPDATE

I just spent two weeks on a client site consulting on a SOLR Cloud installation.  I am now much more familiar with the updates to SOLR, and say quite confidently, I still prefer ElasticSearch, but it seems SOLR has some momentum again.

ElasticSearch, is hands down more elastic.  That is, having an elastic cluster where nodes come and go, or even where you just need to add nodes is much much easier in ElasticSearch than SOLR.  Anyone who tells you it is easy in SOLR, has not done it in ElasticSearch.  ElasticSearch will automatically join a cluster and assume an active role in that cluster, taking over serving available shards and replicas.  Over the last week I decommissioned a 2 node cluster, replacing it with two new nodes.  I simply added the 2 new nodes, and one at a time, marked the other two nodes as non-data nodes.  Once the shard migration completed I decommissioned the nodes.  I had set minimum_master_nodes = 2 ((2/2)+1), and had no issue with split brain.

During the same week, I had to add a node to a SOLR cluster.  The process was poorly documented, especially considering the changes from 4.1 to 4.3 and the mishmash of existing documentation, much of which says you can't even do it based on old versions of SOLR.  I finally found documentation which clarified.  It requires manually adding a core to the collection and then adding replicas to existing shards within the cluster.  Finally you manually decommission the redundant shards on some other node.  At some point this node may become master for one of those shards but not immediately.

With SOLR If you do not have sufficient shards to distribute, you can just add replicas or you can go through a shard split to create two new shards.  Again this is a poorly documented feature, but is functionality that does not exist in ElasticSearch.  You must split and then remove the original shard, something none of the documentation clearly explains.

SolrCloud has a couple other advantages as well if integrating with Hadoop.  If you are indexing data in HDFS or HBase, there are now both Map-Reduce, and real time methods of ingesting data into SOLR.  This provides some real power to your Big Data platform and allows you to do full text search over data that is otherwise barely accessible.

While you can index Hadoop data into ElasticSearch, the implementation is not as clean as the SolrCloud/Cloudera Search implementations.  Having the MapReduce directly build the shards is a far superior solution with significant performance benefits.  Reducers talking directly to a cluster works, but it is not the same.  I do not know if anything similar to the Lily connector for HBase exists for ElasticSearch, if not I may look into writing one. This allows indexing directly from the HBase replication logs.

So in summary there are certainly situations where either is beneficial.  If you are looking for tight integration with `Hadoop`, `SOLR`, `ClouderaSearch` specifically, is a good option.  If you are looking for ease in managing an Elastic cluster, `Elasticsearch` will be a much better option.  For me, I'll continue with my hacky Hadoop integrations to make it work with Elasticsearch, until something better emerges.