# The best search engine for grails app

Tags: grails, solr, elasticsearch, sphinx

That is the best engine for my Grails project.

Requirements for my books project:

- 200k+ entities
- 150k+ unique visitors per day
- meta information search only (book name, chapter name,
  author name...)
- 5-6 data types
- different priority of types. For
  example, book has higher priority then chapter, author has higher
  priority then translator
- suggestions
- possibility of search in specified fields

The contenders are:

- ElasticSearch
- Solr
- Sphinx
- ...

**Update**

Now I'm using ElasticSearch

Comment: you can assign different priorities with the searchable plugin, see the docs for `boost`

Comment: thx for info. But the question is still actual for me

Comment: [Elastic Search plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/elasticsearch) built on top of Lucene is being updated regularly, you also get [boost](http://noamt.github.io/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/guide/mapping.html#propertiesMapping) options. I would go for this plugin if searchable plugin is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a really detailed answer([Solr vs. ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213009/solr-vs-elasticsearch)) for a similar comparison question. I think, you should just care about the scalability and ease of use of the solution here as most of those solution have similar capabilities.

Comment: I have seen this question. I tend to use the Sphinx. That's why I created one more question