# Apache Solr samples for beginner

Tags: solr, search-engine

We are developing an eCommerce site and we want to implement Apache Solr for search engine.

We decided to go with Solr due to its popularity. I am trying to implement Solr with our existing database and looking for online resources to start implementing it.

So I am looking for eCommerce samples to start with. Also any other search engines which can be explored would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler

This will help you to know about how to use solr with RDBMS.

[Solr vs. ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213009/solr-vs-elasticsearch)

[ElasticSearch, Sphinx, Lucene, Solr, Xapian. Which fits for which usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271600/elasticsearch-sphinx-lucene-solr-xapian-which-fits-for-which-usage?lq=1)

[Comparison of full text search engine - Lucene, Sphinx, Postgresql, MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737275/comparison-of-full-text-search-engine-lucene-sphinx-postgresql-mysql)

The above link will guide/enlighten on the other options other than solr.