# Comparison of Handling Logs and PDFs in Solr & Elasticsearch and Data Visualization in Banana & Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene, kibana-4, banana

How do Elasticsearch and Solr compare in respect to the following:

1. Indexing logs.
2. Indexing events.
3. Indexing PDF documents.
4. Ease of creating and distributing visualizations. Kibana vs Banana.
5. Support and documentation for developers.

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**

More specifically, i am trying to figure out how exactly a PDF document or an event can be indexed at all. I have worked a little bit on Elasticsearch and since i am a fan of JSON, i found it quite useful when i tried to index structured data.

For example logs are mostly structured and thus i guess easier to index and search. Now what if i want to index the whole log file itself?

**Follow up**

Is Kibana the only visualization tool available for Elasticsearch?

Is Banana the only visualization tool available for Solr?

Comment: So this doesn't specifically answer your questions at all since you are concentrating on logging, but just something that might be worth a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213009/solr-vs-elasticsearch.  I think the post might really boil down to comparison of banana vs kibana (not what the title conveys).  Another key thing is handling of pdf documents for which you might need to look into plugins (at least for Elasticsearch).

Comment: downvote ? should i be more specific?

Comment: Oh, I did not downvote this.  I think the question can be updated a bit to focus a bit on your requirements and take out the general elasticsearch vs solr stuff.  But to me, it seems like good question that I myself am curious about.  Considering the stackoverflow post I referenced earlier and how popular that was, I don't see why kibana vs banana shouldn't be a good post.  Of course, your post is more than just that.  Have you looked at Logstash as a whole?  But I think the post title and the content itself does require some refining.

Comment: thanks! in the meantime, please feel free to edit the question if you have any suggestions

Comment: I gave it a shot - has to be peer reviewed.  I try to stick with minor edits and not speak for the poster.  But please review if accepted and change it if you don't like it.

Comment: thanks! that was really helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer to try to address just the Elasticsearch aspect of the post.

Take a look at https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments for handling PDFs

For events/logs, you would need to transform those into structured data to index in Elasticsearch.  You can have a field in there for the source (the log file the data came from and other information like that) - you will have all the data in the whole log file indexed in that fashion.  You can take advantage of ES aggregations to group results based on log file, calculate statistics, etc.

The [ELK stack](https://qbox.io/blog/welcome-to-the-elk-stack-elasticsearch-logstash-kibana) is definitely worth a look.

I don't know if Kibana is the only visualization tool but it is probably the most popular and likely to offer more than something else.

Comment: thanks man :) mapper attachment is awesome! is there something similar for Solr?

Comment: Sorry, not really sure about Solr - never worked with it yet.