# What is the difference between AWS Elasticsearch and AWS CloudSearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

When should I use AWS Elasticsearch over AWS CloudSearch and vice versa?

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Amazon Elasticsearch Service** provides a fully-managed implementation of Elasticsearch and Kibana. It is commonly used for near real-time visualizations of logs files (but can handle many use-cases).

**Amazon CloudSearch** is based on Apache Solr. It requires data to be loaded as *documents* and is good for full-text search, with an understanding of languages and grammar (eg synonyms, words to ignore).

So, it really comes down to whether you want to use Elasticsearch or Solr.

Comment: Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10213568/3738870), there aren't really any reasons to use Solr compared to Elasticsearch, so it would be logical to think there aren't really any reasons to use Amazon CloudSearch compared to Amazon Elasticsearch Service, either.