# elasticsearch vs solr - for custom full-text search systems

Tags: java, elasticsearch, solr, lucene, full-text-search

I have a web application with a search engine created internally, based on Lucene indexes.

The application allows full text search.

The application is built in jsp and java.

To index user the Hadoop distributed processing software.

The Apache lucene project was customized to our specific case. Mainly the part of full-text search, to add new features of ordering results.

The front end uses hadoop-rpc to communicate with the backend, which in turn has created an internal solution (10 years ago) that researches in Lucene's indecisions.

The code is legacy, it needs a migration to another type of software. Here's the question: **ElasticSearch** vs. **Solr**?

The requirements are:

- open-source, the purpose is to customize to accept specific features
  of the application's ranking.
- Working with Lucene indexes (since you
  do not want to reindex all over again).
- Speed are very important factors.

I have read some articles on the subject, but I wanted a personalized opinion for my case, any idea of which one will be the best option?

Thanks

Comment: Both will work perfectly fine. Which will work best will depend on factors beyond what can be described here and your details requirements, but usually it'll be "good enough" for both platforms. They're both Lucene at the heart anyway.

Comment: Please refer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213009/solr-vs-elasticsearch?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

SolR and Elasticsearch are quite similar. They both have the features you need.

It's a very open question and my opinion will be that Elasticsearch will be a better pick, it has a bigger community and tend to grow faster.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The more custom you need your solution to be, the more likely you will benefit from Solr.

While both of them use Lucene under the covers, Solr exposes more of it directly. Elasticsearch is tuned more for logs and things and some text search configuration is harder to access.

Comment: Okay, I got the idea. Which one has the best technical support? The best code that can be customizable? From what I see both have a good online community, but which one is better for the case of a custom search engine?

Comment: Solr has better customization as absolutely everything is open-source. Elastic probably has better - paid - support. Free support, I don't know.