# The best search solution for a university website which has high-traffic time to time

Tags: search, solr, elasticsearch, search-engine, sphinx

We are building a university website and finding a search solution for it. Our university website has high-traffic because it has faculty of open university so very much students (approximately 1.5 million). Even we use caching for speeding up the website. Anyway, which search engine do you suggest for our situation?

**Note:** We think Solr, Elasticsearch or Sphinx for now, but also it can be one of the others.

**Update:** We need a full-text search engine which must be fast, extendable and with the features like query likening and indicating priority support.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you say why you downvoted my question, so i can learn my wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on your use-case, what features you want, and whether you have any experience with any of the technologies. I could paraphrase arguments, but there's a very good discussion here: [ElasticSearch, Sphinx, Lucene, Solr, Xapian. Which fits for which usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271600/elasticsearch-sphinx-lucene-solr-xapian-which-fits-for-which-usage) that covers the pros and cons of each.

**Edit (in response to the question's edit):**

Of these technologies I have only used Solr (and SQL), but I've found it to be easy to use and would recommend it. It supports native sharding and replication, which should cover the extendibility issue. It also supports things like joins and field weighting, which I think covers all your needs if I read your requirements correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed my answer to specify a few requirements.

Comment: We don't work about search engines and we have a limited time for finishing the website project. So can we adapt Solr in this short time or should we use more lightweight solution like Elasticsearch(i guess)?

Comment: In my experience I built a decent search system with multiple indexes and full-text search, with a JS/PHP secure API and query builder using Solarium in a little over a week with no prior experience. As I said I've never used Elasticsearch, only Solr, so you should read up on the link I posted, and its related questions, if you're in any doubt as to what you want to use, but I think with some competence it should be possible to build what you want in a limited time.