# Does Elastic Search performance get affected on Relational database models such as MySQL?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, elasticsearch, orm, hibernate-search

I am using Hibernate search with hibernate 4 with MYSQL database spring MVC application .It is evident that elastic search is a high performance search engine but the cost of indexing on RDMS such as MYSQL is a concern.I would like to know if elastic search is suitable for Relational Database or I should stick to Hibernate search?

Comment: This answer might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11963981/4604579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is that Hibernate search is starting to support elasticsearch.

An example here: https://github.com/dadoonet/hsearch-es-demo/tree/02-hibernatesearch?files=1