# conversion SQL query with LIKE operator to SQL query with filters

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to convert SQL query with `LIKE` operator to SQL query with only equality and inequality filters and not `LIKE` operator. Output of both the queries must be same.

If it is possible, how it is done?

I am using MySQL database.

I tried for solution but with no success.

Comment: In some cases this may be possible, not all though. Post your query and what you've tried so far. It may also be a good idea to say why you need to do this, other people may know a better solution to your problem. `REGEXP` for example.

Comment: @klennepette any query which requires LIKE operator. Ex- find the name of student having first two letters SR..

Comment: @SRK It is not possible. I do wonder why you would need to do this.

Comment: @xdazz Actually I am working on query optimization..

Comment: @SRK: Read the MySQL documentation on query optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

Without using any kind of `function` (as you stated as a comment in @jonlester answer) it is impossible to do what you want.

A way to do it with a simple function would be like this:

```
select
  mycol
from
  mytbl
where 
  INSTR(mycol,test) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand your question, but you can use mysql functions in this way:

```
select
  mycol
from
  mytbl
where 
  mycol like "test%"
```

will be the same as:

```
select
  mycol
from
  mytbl
where 
  left(mycol,4) = "test"
```

Comment: question is I want to use equality and inequality filters only(not even aggregate function) to provide functionality of LIKE. Is it possible?

Comment: @jonlester that doesn't work for all `like`s. Ex: `like "%test%`

Answer (score 0):

You have two options...

```
1. SELECT myColumn FROM myTable WHERE INSTR(myColumn,'myString') = 1

2. SELECT myColumn FROM myTable WHERE LOCATE('myString',myColumn) = 1
```

Good Luck!!! Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `LIKE` to find sub-elements **at the time a column is being queried** then you could split those sub-elements off into separate columns **at the time they are inserted/updated** to enable the use of the equality operator in search conditions.

Answer (score 0):

As you specify your requirements, I think you should be looking in the direction of integrating full-text indexes.

Ie. look at solutions like SOLR, Lucene or similar. You might want to start here [Search Engine - Lucene or Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400892/search-engine-lucene-or-solr) - and click/google your way from there.